# Magnolia CMS: Problems calling function 'cmsfn:linkForWorkspace'

Tags: jsp, content-management-system, magnolia

I'm running two Magnolia environments (one for testing and a productive one, both 4.5.2 CE). Now on my testing installation my script is working fine. On the other (productive) environment I get an templating error even though I copied everything from the good working testing environment.

My Script:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="cmsfn" uri="http://magnolia-cms.com/taglib/templating-components/cmsfn" %>

<c:set var="imageLink1" value="${cmsfn:linkForWorkspace(content.image1,content.image1DmsUUID)}"/>
<c:if test="${cmsfn:isPublicInstance()}">
    <c:set var="imageLink1" value="${fn:replace(imageLink1, 'magnoliaPublic', 'content')}" />
</c:if>
```

And here's what fails on the productive system only (from catalina.out):
http://pastebin.com/ANtEjBCW

You see, the error is "Problems calling function 'cmsfn:linkForWorkspace'". But why is it working on the testing system?

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: javax.jcr.NoSuchWorkspaceException:
```

That gives you the clue. Most likely whatever you have in *content.image1* doesn't contain valid workspace name in your prod env while it does in your test env. Basically I think it's the data issue, not the script issue.

Comment: Hi Jan! Thanks for your answer ;) As you suggested there could be something wrong with the workspace, I printed out both _content.image1_ and _content.image1DmsUUID_ to see if I return "dms" as in my test env. And I do! So somehow it's not finding the "dms" workspace, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, the data in your prod system are missing the "workspace" name. I'm not sure how exactly you have created your data, but it seems like you used the DAMHandler. If you haven't changed default configuration then it is possible for user to choose between DMS and Upload, so it's quite possible that while in your test env, you have image that is link to DMS, in your prod env user chose to change the image and uploaded some manually. You should check what the prod data are exactly.